# Closure Properties of recursively enumerable languages

Tags: algorithm, product, difference, turing-machines, set-theory

Please consider the following question:

Let `L1` and `L2` be two languages. Prove or disprove the closedness of the class of r.e. languages under

1. difference `(L1 - L2)`
2. product `(L1 x L2)`
   (Try to prove product under the assumption that is known where the word of `L1` ends as wells as for the case where it is not known.

Here, closedness means that if `L1` and `L2` can be accepted by a touring machine, then also `(L1 - L2)` or `(L1 x L2)`

**Notes**

I am able to figure out a solution for union and complement (union: closed; complement: not closed), but not for the above (difference or product).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it addresses a purely abstract problem in computer science and therefore fits in better at cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

1) RE is not closed under difference.

Proof: 
Assume it was.

Let `Sigma` be the alphabet of an arbitrary RE language `L`. `Sigma^*` is RE (TM just checks that the input string either only contains symbols from `Sigma` or else is empty). If RE would be closed under difference, in particular `Sigma^* - L` would be RE. But then any RE language would be recursive ( decidable ). However, there are undecidable RE languages ( cf. halting problem ).

2) RE is closed under Cartesian product

Proof sketch:
Assume first that an oracle provide the correct partition of the input string into words from `L1`, `L2`.
In that case, run TMs `T1`, `T2` to check containment in `L1`, `L2`, resp., sequentially on their inputs. This setup terminates iff both TMs terminate.

Next assume that there is no oracle. For any given input string `w`, there are  `length(w)+1`possible partitions. Run `length(w)+1` copies of the concatenated TMs `T1`, `T2` in parallel, one for each partition, on the inputs from the respective partition. This setup terminates iff at least one of the cloned TM concatenation terminates which is equivalent to the input string portions are members of `L1`, `L2`, resp.